# Lifecycle of object and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, destroy, stdthread

We are passing the object to another thread. It suppose to be deleted when oops2 () function is out of scope. How is it possible that after deleting data object we do not have crash in another thread and another thread is successfully working with that object?

```
class Data {
public:
    Data(int val = 0) {}
    int getVal () const { return mVal; }
    void setVal(int val) { mVal = val; }
protected:
    int mVal;
};

void set_val(int& i, Data* data)
{
    data->setVal(i);
}

void print_val(Data* data)
{
    cout << "Data value = " << data->getVal() << endl;
}

struct func2
{
    Data* data;
    func2(Data* data_): data(data_){}

    void operator()()
    {
        printf("Address of func2 data is %p\n", data);
        for (int j=0;j < 1000000;++j)
        {
            print_val(data);
            set_val(j, data);
        }
    }
};

void oops2()
{
    Data* data = new Data(100);
    func2 my_func(data);
    my_thread = std::thread(my_func);
    delete data;
}

int main()
{
    oops2();
    my_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is not guaranteed to cause a crash. It is allowed to misbehave (or *seem* to work) in any way imaginable. Just don't write code with UB.

Comment: Yes, but I am accessing it in another thread. If we put cout for each j you can see that we are working with object that was deleted?

Comment: And working with a deleted object *is* UB. All bets are off - the code is broken and you cannot reason about any behaviour you observe. A different compiler or different optimization setting may give you different results. You have broken the rules of the language and the compiler is now free to do whatever it pleases. You have *no* guarantees any more. And the compiler is *not* required to warn you when you do something that is undefined.